# webpack-dev-server command getting cannot find module 'http-parser-js'

Tags: angularjs, webpack-dev-server

In one of the project setup, I followed as given the instructions.

```
>sudo npm install -g gulp

>sudo npm install -g coffee-script

>sudo npm install -g webpack

>sudo npm install -g webpack-dev-server

#Install development dependencies
>npm install
```

To start the project ran gulp command it ran succesfully.

```
>./node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

Then ran the webpack-dev-server

```
>./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --inline
```

Getting following error

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'http-parser-js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/http_parser.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I tried removing node_modules folder install again but no luck. Let me anything I am missing.

Comment: Just wondering, but why did you need sudo access to install global dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

npm i http-parser-js -g

Try above